# Efficient way of printing property names in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Hello  i am new to Haskell and i was wondering :

For every new defined type constructor even if it is something with 0 depth eg.:

```
data Letter =A | B | C deriving (Show)
```

do i have to provide

```
instance Show Type
    Letter A = "A"
    Letter B ="B"
    Letter C ="C"
```

I understand that for nested types you have to provide `Show` implementation but for something simple is there no other way to just use something equivalent to reflection (C#) ? Just get the property name / constructor name  and  `ToString`*-it* ?

Do haskell programmers provide instances for `Show` for any adhoc type they create?

By nested types i mean having a simple ADT inside another ADT inside another etc..but all you want is to get their names:

e.g:

```
data Person = Male | Female
data IsMarried=Yes | No

data Worker=Worker{
            person::Person,
            status::IsMarried
            }
```

For this kind of nesting do i really have to define `instance` of `Show` for all these type constructors even though all i want is their name be "stringified"?

Comment: You have to instruct GHC how to render your type, yes. If you use ```deriving Show``` you do not need to provide an instance of ```Show```.

Comment: If you add `deriving Show` the compiler writes the instance for you. Unless you want it to be different from the compiler's default, there's no need to write it on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since @AJFarmar edit back his answer when i change it:

> Do I have to provide [a show instance for every type?]

Yes. Either by deriving it with `deriving Show`, or by supplying a type instance

`instance Show -type- where...`

> I understand that for nested types you have to provide Show implementation[...]

Yes you do, the compiler will not add any necessary instances for Show.

```
data Test = Test -- no instance for Show

test :: String
test = show $ (Just Test :: Maybe Test)
```

Will not compile with the error message:

```
main.hs:4:8: error:
    • No instance for (Show Test) arising from a use of ‘show’
    • In the expression: show $ (Just Test :: Maybe Test)
      In an equation for ‘test’: test = show $ (Just Test :: Maybe Test)
```

Which is why you need to have a `Show` instance for `a` aswell. If one already exists, you do not have to supply a new one, however.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have to provide [a show instance for every type?]

No, because you have automatically derived `Show`:

```
data Letter = A | B | C deriving (Show)
--                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Here
```

However, if you want a 'smarter' `show`, such as displaying a custom list as `[1,2,3]` rather than a mess of constructors, you're going to have to write it yourself.

You can do the same for a number of classes (Including `Eq`,`Ord`,`Read`,`Enum`, and `Bounded`) but most classes, including user-defined classes, must be implemented manually without the use of certain language extensions.

> I understand that for nested types you have to provide Show implementation[...]

You do not! For instance, I can write this:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing deriving (Show)
```

And the compiler will automatically add the necessary constraints, despite it being a 'nested' type.

> Just get the property name / constructor name and ToString-it ?

There are no 'properties' in Haskell - don't think in terms of C# here. `show` is the equivalent of `ToString`.  However, a form of type reflection is available in [TypeReps](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html), though I would advise not using this until you have a solid grasp on Haskell.

Comment: You can not magically derive ```Show``` for any polymorphic data type. The polymorphic types must also have instances of ```Show```.

Comment: @RobertK Quote: "And the compiler will automatically add the necessary constraints." I'm fully aware the `a` in `Maybe a` must also be an instance of `Show`.

Comment: The compiler will not automatically add an instance of ```Show``` for ```a```. This is where i claim you are wrong.

Comment: @RobertK I do not claim that. By 'nested type' I think the asker means a type like `Maybe`, not the type argument.

Comment: why would it make any sense that ```Maybe``` is the nested type in question?

Comment: @RobertK The compiler will not add an instance of `Show` for `a`, but it will add a constraint to the derived instance demanding `Show a` (producing e.g. `instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) where ...`).

Comment: @DanielWagner yes i am perfectly aware of that. That is however not what AJFarmar was implying in his answer. The statement was "I understand that for nested types you have to provide Show implementation" and AJ's answer was "You do not". I think it is misleading/unclear as there is always a need for that instance. You do not yourself however have to supply it, if one already exists.

Comment: @RobertK I suspect that what you mean by nested types is "types contained in another type", while what the original question asker meant was "types that contain another type". Perhaps this explains the confusion in the conversation thus far.

Comment: I am sorry for late response.For nested types i was meaning having ADT inside ADT. Something like `data Person=Male | Female` and  `data IsMarried=Yes | No`   in `data Worker=Worker{ type::Person , status::IsMarried}` .I didn't know if you have to provide show for each level of ADT even though you do not want any specific behaviour you just want the name of the data constructor `toString`.